# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find button "Log in" that is not disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capybara

I'm running an acceptance test that includes logging in via /users/sign_in.

**How do I set up the test so I can "click" the submit button within a Rspec Capybara test?**

Seems that Devise disables the Login submit button and runs javascript to make things work.

```
<%= f.submit "Log in" %>
```

produces:

```
 <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Log In" tabindex="4" data-disable-with="Log In" />
```

The data-disable-with, which devise needs, seems to be breaking capybara testing. I would just like to click the button as per my acceptance test below.

```
it "logs in and shows success message" do
  visit '/users/sign_in'
  login_as(user, :scope => :user)
  within(".login-details") do
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'fakepassword'
  end
  click_button 'Log in'
  expect(page).to have_content 'Success'
end
```

Is producing:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:  Unable to find button "Log in" that is not disabled
```

Note: I have multiple pages that logging in can send a user to, this example is the simplest test that reveals this bug. So no my goal is not to 'make sure devise works', incase you were wondering 'why do they need this?'

Comment: Are you using selenium? Poltergeist?

Comment: Currently selenium, but happy to switch over if it's better/will make a difference.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was asking are you running this headless or is it firing up a browser?

Comment: Running it Headless

Answer (score 3):

The `data-disable-with` attribute is used by Rails UJS to change the buttons text after it's been clicked so wouldn't be affecting this test.  Looking at the HTML element you posted the `value` of the button is 'Log In' so, since case matters, you'd need to do

```
click_button 'Log In'
```

rather than 'Log in'

I do wonder why you have `login_as(user, :scope => :user)` in the same code where you're filling in the username and password though, you'd normally only use `login_as` when you wanted to bypass actually filling in the form and logging in.